# ¿Cómo remover breadcrumbs del theme Generate press?

Tags: css, wordpress

Quiero sacar los breadcrumbs que aparecen en la parte inferior del blog, intenté con este CSS pero no pasó nada:

```
/* Remove bredcrumbs from post */

.breadcrumb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Dejo una imagen por si no se entendió qué es lo que quiero quitar: https://prnt.sc/qixcsr

Estoy usando como Theme, Generate press

Comment: Y vos estas seguro que el breadcrumb que muestra el theme tiene esa class?

Comment: Muy buena pregunta! Me hiciste dar cuenta que la class estaba mal. La class de Generate press es .entry-meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la class de Generate press es .entry-meta 
Así que sería:

```
.entry-meta {
    display: none !important;
}
```